# Can't install gnome-terminal-transparency on Arch Linux cinnamon

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome

I started setup arch linux on virtual machine vmware. Then I decide to make transparency on the terminal and found that gnome-terminal disabled that feature after version 3.7.

So I tried to install gnome terminal with transparency but there was an issue

`gnome-terminal-3.42.1/src/meson.build:172:0: ERROR: gnome.genmarshal keyword argument 'sources' was of type array[File] but should have been array[str] that cannot be empty`

and

`A full log can be found at /var/tmp/pamac-build-makuta/gnome-terminal-transparency/src/build/meson-logs/meson-logs.txt`

`==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().`

but at the end of that giant log file was the same as I write first

Also, I tried to install gnome terminal fedora but it gives the same issue.
Maybe there are a good alternative of gnome terminal?

Comment: This *should* work; I installed the `gnome-terminal-transparency` package without a hitch, both on **Arch** and **EndeavourOS**.

Comment: Hmmm...seeing the same complaints on the EOS forums; not sure why it works for some, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade a mason pkg to version 6.0 for it to compile, its a bug currently
Use a AUR pkg named Downgrade to do that!